# Comparing spectral radius of two graphs using the entry of Perron vector

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Suppose we have a graph $G$.

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of $G$ and $x$ be the corresponding Perron vector.

Let $x = (x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)^t$, where $x_i$ corresponds to the vertex $i \in V(G)$.

We further assume that $x_u > x_v$ and $H$ be a graph.

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be the graphs obtained from $G$ by attaching $H$ to the vertex $u$ and $v$, respectively.

By attaching I mean to identify a vertex, say $w \in V(H)$, with $u$ to create $G_1$ and then with $v$ to create $G_2$.

Let $\rho(G)$ denote the spectral radius of $G$.

$$\textbf{Claim:} \rho(G_1) > \rho(G_2).$$

---

Is the claim true? Is there any reference where I can find this result?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you like to elaborate on how we should attach $H$ to the vertices $u$ and $v$ respectively?

Comment: @JosephVanName By attaching I mean identifying one vertex of $H$ with $u$ to create $G_1$, and same with $v$ to create $G_2$.

Comment: Are the graphs $G_1,G_2,H$ all disjoint?

Comment: @JosephVanName H is disjoint from G. But G_1 and G_2 are two different graphs both are created from G.